# How to prove the matrix inequality $\sqrt{\det{(A^2-AB+B^2)}}+\sqrt{\det{(A^2+AB+B^2)}}\ge |\det{(A)}+\det{(B)}|$

Tags: matrices, inequality

Let $A,B\in M_{2}(R)$ be two square matrices so that
$AB=BA$, prove the inequality

$$\sqrt{\det{(A^2-AB+B^2)}}+\sqrt{\det{(A^2+AB+B^2)}}\ge |\det{(A)}
+\det{(B)}|$$
I only know prove this
$$\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}\ge |a+b|,a,b\in R$$
because
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\ge\sqrt{x+y}$$
so
$$LHS\ge\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}\ge (a+b)$$

But for matrices I can't prove it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user 1551 points out, it suffices to prove the inequality for $AB = BA$ where, $A,B$ are invertible. Since, commuting matrices preserve each others eigenspaces, they are simultaneous diagonalisable, $\exists \, U \in U_2(\mathbb{R})$, such that $U^{-1}AU = D[x_1,y_1] = D_1$ and $U^{-1}BU = D[x_2,y_2] = D_2$.

Thus, $\displaystyle \sqrt{\det{(A^2-AB+B^2)}}+\sqrt{\det{(A^2+AB+B^2)}}\ge |\det{(A)}
+\det{(B)}| \iff \sqrt{\det{(D_1^2-D_1D_2+D_2^2)}}+\sqrt{\det{(D_1^2+D_1D_2+D_2^2)}}\ge |\det{(D_1)}
+\det{(D_2)}|$

(since, $|\det(U)| = 1$)

That is,

$\displaystyle \sqrt{(x_1^2-x_1x_2+x_2^2)(y_1^2-y_1y_2+y_2^2)}+\sqrt{(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_1y_2+y_2^2)} \ge |x_1y_1+x_2y_2| \iff \left(\frac{3}{4}(x_1-x_2)^2+\frac{1}{4}(x_1+x_2)^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{3}{4}(y_1-y_2)^2+\frac{1}{4}(y_1+y_2)^2\right)^{1/2} + \left(\frac{1}{4}(x_1-x_2)^2+\frac{3}{4}(x_1+x_2)^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{4}(y_1-y_2)^2+\frac{3}{4}(y_1+y_2)^2\right)^{1/2} \ge_{C.S.} \frac{3}{4}|x_1-x_2||y_1-y_2|+\frac{1}{4}|x_1+x_2||y_1+y_2|+\frac{1}{4}|x_1-x_2||y_1-y_2|+\frac{3}{4}|x_1+x_2||y_1+y_2| \ge |x_1y_1+x_2y_2|$ (by triangle inequality).

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to the party and I haven't time to cook up a full solution, but here are some observations.

As $A$ commutes with $B+\epsilon I$ for every real $\epsilon$, by continuity, it suffices to prove the inequality for invertible $B$. Let $X=B^{-1}A$. Divide both sides of the inequality by $|\det(B)|$, the inequality becomes
$$
\sqrt{\det{(X^2-X+I)}}+\sqrt{\det{(X^2+X+I)}}\ge |\det{(X)}+1|.
$$
When $X$ has two real eigenvalues $x,y$, the inequality becomes
$$
\sqrt{(x^2 - x + 1)(y^2 - y + 1)} + \sqrt{(x^2 + x + 1)(y^2 + y + 1)}
\ge |1 + xy|.\tag{1}
$$
When $X$ has a pair of conjugate complex eigenvalues $z$ and $\bar{z}$, the inequality becomes
$$
|z^2 - z + 1| + |z^2 + z + 1| \ge 1 + |z|^2.\tag{2}
$$
Hence the problem boils down to proving $(1)$ and $(2)$.